# Git blind spot between staging and remote

Tags: git, visual-studio-2015, git-diff

I'm relatively new to git having come from a VSS / TFS / SVN background. I'm using the git plugin in Visual Studio 2015.

So I clone a repository and make some changes to a code file. Then I look at the changes tab (which I presume does a git diff in the background) and I see the changes I made. All fine and dandy.

Then I commit the changes to my local repo, after which I make some more changes to a local file, view the changes, and commit again.

My problem is that there's now a blind spot between my local repo and the remote one - I've lost visibility of the differences between local and remote. This has been confusing me since I started working with git.

Am I doing it all wrong... afaik "git diff" shows the changes between my local working code base and local repo. How do I easily see the difference between the changes that have been accumulating in my local repo and the code on the remote repository?

Comment: By "local staging area" do you just mean your local clone of the repo?  If so, the problem you're describing is usually achieved by creating a feature branch to do your work on.  Then you can see the diff by doing `git diff <main_branch> <feature_branch>`.

Comment: If you are coming from an SVN background, you need a new mindset. In SVN, the repository is somewhere far away. You extract things to a work-tree and your work-tree is all you have. When you are ready to commit you send this all back to the distant server. With Git, you don't do that at all: you get *every* version locally, keep them in Git's commits and Git's branches (which are very different), make new commits locally, and compare commits, all in your own repository with no help from the server. Then, at a time you choose, you [continued]

Comment: ... you connect your Git to their Git and either get new commits *from* them (`git fetch`) or give your commits *to* them (`git push`). Until you do either of these, your repository and their repository continue to drift apart. If their repository is mostly inactive, you can just compare and push, otherwise you must fetch first, see what's changed there, re-sync *your* work, and only *then* push. In any case, note that you have everything they have (except if you need to `git fetch` first), so you compare in *your* repository.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, by "local staging area" I mean the staging / index area that we stage files to before committing them. According to this the staging area sits between the local workspace and the local repository: [http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html](http://ndpsoftware.com/git-cheatsheet.html)

Comment: Hi @torek, from what you're saying I guess my issue is that I lose visibility beteen my local repo and the remote one

Comment: Your local branch is now two commits *ahead* of the remote. The git history window in Visual Studio should visualize this, or the Sync tab in the git pane should also tell you about this.

Comment: @Oliver I probably should have used local repo where I had said staging area. I updated the question to reflect this

Comment: Is there also a blind spot regarding the changes that are in the VS window (as yet unsaved), those changes that have been saved within this session, and the original unchanged code of this VS session (coloured sidebars of old)? That three way distinction has a similarity with Git's three way distinction between 'changed', 'staged/added' and 'committed', so there is a posibility of confusion between the different indicators. [I've not used the new VS with Git integration, so I'm positting possible issues]

Comment: @Philip yes I think the 3 way thing you mention is kind of what's tripping me up.. the differences between changed / staged / comitted and the differences between the local and remote repos

Comment: @Lasse yes I'm starting to figure out and realise that the Sync tab lists all the changes that have been committed locally

Answer (score 0):

You will want to diff *commits*.  In particular, you will want to diff the *current commit that is the tip-most commit that is in another repository* against the tip-most commit in *your own* repository.  But in the most general case, you cannot do that until you *copy* that commit—the other repository's commit—to *your* repository.  This is because you are always working in *your own* repository, except for the brief periods when you connect your repository to a second Git with a second repository.

This might be best illustrated visually (which requires showing a graphical representation of branching, which—at least in terms of physical implementation—is very different in Git than it is in SVN).  Consider this drawing:

```
             o--o--U   <-- commits you made
            /
...--o--o--B    [shared with another repository at the start]
            \
             o--T   <-- commits they made when you weren't looking
```

I gave letters to three of the "most interesting" commits (the others are just round `o` nodes).  Newer commits are towards the right.  The commits you have made are on the top line.  Commits "they" made, that you have to bring in before you can do comparisons, are on the bottom line.  Commits that both you and they had *in common* before you started all this are on the middle line.

I believe you are asking how you compare the contents of `U` (for Us or oUrs) to the contents of `T` (for Them).  The way to do that is with `git diff` plus the hash IDs of the two commits `U` and `T`.  Note, however, that you can compare *any* pair of commits, such as `B` (for Base) vs `U` and `B` vs `T`, as well.  When you *merge* your work with their work, Git will automatically compare `B`-vs-`U` and `B`-vs-`T`.

To *get* the bottom row of commits you must run `git fetch`.

If you are coming from SVN, many of these concepts themselves will be unfamiliar.

## Git vs SVN: a 30,000 foot overview

I will expand a bit on what I said in comments, but still sticking to a high level view—one that, as much as possible, avoids mentioning branches, which SVN implements very differently.  For a slightly deeper rapid introduction to Git branches, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44081446/1256452 (an answer to [need clarification on pulling git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44080467/1256452)).

#### One repository vs many repositories

In SVN, there is only one actual repository.  That repository, which holds every commit ever, is "far away" on some server somewhere, rather than on your computer.  To work on something, you grab a bunch of code out of the repository.  This puts the code on your own machine, where you can work on it.  You do some work and when you are ready, you tell your machine:

- Show me what I have, compared to what's on the server
- Send what I have back to the server to make a commit

Git usage is *very* different.  There is not just one repository.  There is one repository *per user*, or perhaps even more-than-one per user (you can make as many clones as you like, and each one is a repository in its own right).  Your repository has every commit ever, and so does every other copy (every "clone").  Of course, each clone *starts out* the same as the original, but they do drift apart over time.  How fast they drift apart depends on how active each clone is.

Because separate repository clones exist, you need something SVN doesn't: a way to *synchronize two repositories*.  In Git, these are called *push* and *fetch*.  (You might think they should be push and *pull*, and in Mercurial, they *are*, but Git kind of over-defined *pull* initially and had to back up and introduce *fetch*.  Don't use Git's *pull* right away, it mixes together two different ideas and will lead you astray.)

Remember that whenever you are using these operations, there are *two* Gits involved, with *two* repositories.  Each of these repositories is a complete repository in and of itself, with its own full set of commits, and ways to name those commits (Git calls these "branches" and "tags" and the purposes are similar, but these are very different from SVN's—you'll be best served by thinking, initially, about *commits* rather than "branches").

When you first make your own clone, or do a `git fetch` to get your clone updated from its origin—which is cleverly named `origin`—what your Git does is *rename* their Git's commits.  Since you have just cloned, or just run `git fetch`, your repository is now *the same as*, or *a superset of*, theirs.  You now have everything they do, plus perhaps a bit more.

Hence, when you want to see what you have that they *don't*—particularly, how your most recent commit compares to theirs—you simply do:

```
git fetch origin    # get me their latest things
```

and then:

```
git diff <their-latest-commit> <my-latest-commit>
```

to compare their highest revision to yours.

#### Revision numbering: why Git hash IDs are weird

There is a separate problem here, which I won't get into deeply, but will touch on.  In SVN, "highest revision" is easy to tell, because there's only one *repository* and revisions are numbered sequentially.  If your revision is number 128 and theirs is number 127, obviously yours is later than theirs, but if yours is 128 and theirs is 129, obviously theirs is later than yours.  But here in Git, when you `git fetch`, you have *two* repositories.  What if when you cloned, there were 127 commits, but both you *and* they have added one commit each?  Now you both have 128 commits.  You then cross-connect their Git to your Git and yank in their new commits, and now you have 129 commits and they have 128 commits.  What happens?

The first and most important thing that happens is that commits aren't numbered *sequentially* at all, so that your Git and their Git don't have to fight over who gets to call this "revision 128".  Instead, Git commit IDs are big, ugly, incomprehensible *hash IDs*.  The exact hash ID is something Git assigns *when you make the commit*.  Git guarantees that *your* hash IDs for your new commits never collide with *their* hash IDs for *their* new commits.

This is what allows you to cross-connect the two Gits in the first place: initially, your Git and their Git exchange just their latest hash IDs.  These, plus algorithmic tricks using properties of Directed Acyclic Graphs, mean that your Git and their Git can quickly determine *all* the commits (and other Git objects) that need to be copied to complete a fetch or push.  Even if the initial clone of a repository takes many minutes or hours, a fetch or push can usually complete in a few seconds at most (though this depends on the amount of data that you must transfer, how fast your two computers are, and how fast the network is between them).

In this particular example (where you both added commit "128"), these new commits go "in parallel" when compared to older ones:

```
             o   <-- your 128th commit
            /
...--o--o--o   <-- 127 commits in a row here
            \
             o   <-- their 128th commit
```

This forking of commit streams is a kind of *branch* and leads to what Git calls "branches", which as I said I am not going to get into here.  But essentially, you compare *your* 128th (or higher) commit to *their* 128th (or higher) commit, and/or to the *merge base* commit, which is the last commit that you both had in common before you started to drift apart by adding new commits.

#### Public vs private commits, or, a few words about making all this function correctly

To make all this work, Git depends on the idea that whatever happens with these repository clones, you only add new commits.

This is sort of a lie: the word *depends* here is too strong.  When you cross-connnect two Git repositories, the one that *acquires new commits* just gets the *new ones*.  If the user of the other Git has thrown away some commits, then one of two things holds:

- You already had the commits they threw out.  You still have them.  You have merely added *new* commits to your technological distinctiveness.
- You never had the commits they threw out.  You still don't have them.  You have merely added their *remaining* new commits to your technological distinctiveness.

The principle here should be clear, or at least clear-ish, though: your Git is not throwing anything away when you connect your Git to their Git.  Your Git is only *adding new things*.

The same normally goes for a `git push` operation: your Git will give their Git *new* commits, not take some away.  It's very difficult (and somewhat error-prone) to take things away.  It *can* be done, via what Git calls a *force push*, but the mechanism is somewhat involved and requires getting down into the details of Git's branches and other of what Git calls *references*.  So in general, you should endeavor to only add *new* commits—or at least, only add new commits once you *publish* a commit by giving it to another Git.

When you first add new commits to your repository, these new commits are *only* in *your* repository.  At this point, you can discard them,<sup>1</sup> or copy-and-replace them,<sup>2</sup> or whatever, with great freedom.  But once you *share* those commits with another Git, that other Git has those commits, which it knows by their magic hash IDs.  It's now very difficult to retract them.

Unless you have your own server and allow others to `git fetch` *from* you, in general, you publish commits using `git push`.  So if you have not yet pushed a commit—if you have only used `git fetch`—you are free to rework it.  (Mercurial keeps track of whether a commit has been published, using something called a *commit phase*.  Git doesn't, but Git's reference system—what Git calls *remote-tracking branches*, which is a terrible phrase—can help you out here.  But that, again, gets into branches, which I am trying to avoid.)

Note that it's easy to *undo* a commit without taking it back: just add a *new* commit that reverses the effect of the previous commit.  Git calls this a *revert;* Mercurial calls it a *backout*.  Either way, though, you're adding *new* commits, which makes everything work smoothly.  So once you have published commits, you can revert them, and there are no complicated "everyone must agree to retract" issues with that.  The only drawback is that now you have a mistake and its correction, published forever for the world to see. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>To discard commits, you can use `git reset`—though I will note here that `git reset` is a bit of a Frankenstein monster of a command made of three different parts.  It doesn't necessarily *discard* commits: you can use it to discard uncommitted work instead, or at the same time.  In fact, you can even use it to *resurrect* commits!

<sup>2</sup>To *replace* an entire chain of commits with an entire new chain—the "chain" can be as short as you like, including just one commit long—use `git rebase`.  Rebase is a bit complicated technically; it's probably wiser to start with `git merge`, since *each* copied commit is technically made *by* merging.  Note that those incomprehensible hash IDs *change* in the new copies, since the new commits are different from the originals.  Merging avoids the copy-and-change-ID thing, by (normally) creating a new *merge commit*.

Comment: Whilst this is all very good material, it's unclear if/where it answers the actual question :/

Comment: I think the explanation missed out the extra point that the difference in view poinst between historical VCS systems and Distributed versioning systems (like Git) cause a lot of XY-Problem confusions for new users. The core differences are at a quite fundamental level and can be as difficult to grok as functional programming is to imperative programmers.

Comment: @PhilipOakley: I skipped over file- vs commit-based as SVN *does* work on a commit-at-a-time basis (though, due to the modeling of branches-as-file-trees, this *can* be a problem).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I agree, but I'm not sure what else to mention. One must grasp Git's odd branch naming system (via the linked answer), and only then one can see how to `git fetch` any new commits made on the remote, then diff, merge, or rebase as desired. It's a lot to do at once.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I took a stab at adding a more direct answer before the high level overview.

Comment: @torek, thanks, I was mainly reflecting on Oliver's initial response that desired an answer to one of the OPs specific questions, however I thought that the OP had a bit of an XY-problem issue that started from using the wrong mental model. Your answer covered the differences, but hadn't explicitly got that highest level summary, rather it was inferred. The XY problem solution (as you know) is backing out of the misunderstanding rather than digging deeper with a misguided point solution. I thought your over view was pretty good.

Comment: @torek excellent answer thanks a lot.. above and beyond the call of duty :) I'll be reading this a few times and letting it sink in